# getting duplicate column while creating csv file in php

Tags: php

```
    $stmt =$this->db->prepare("select * from abstract where account_name=:account_name");
    $stmt->bindparam(':account_name',$name);
    $stmt->execute();
    $getAccountInfo=$stmt->fetchAll();
    return $getAccountInfo;
```

csv file concept is

```
if (isset($_POST['xyz'])) {
    $randnum = rand(1111111111,9999999999);

    if (isset($data['0'])) {
        $fp= fopen("contacts_$randnum.csv","w");
        foreach ($data AS $values) {
            fputcsv($fp, $values);
        }
        fclose($fp);
    }
}
```

when i submit post request i am getting csv file with duplicate column

[image]

Comment: Just checking this is correct (not a fix) `if(isset($data['0'])){`. Did you mean `$data[0]`?

Comment: PXgamer is correct, remove the single quotes

Comment: still i am getting same record,i can remove if concept then also i can able to create csv file

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$getAccountInfo=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: @ArifKhan No problem Arif

Comment: This is only 50% of a good answer. It's missing an explanation of what leads to the OP's unexpected behaviour. "Try x/y" has no learning effect, only copy paste.

Comment: @DanFromGermany  Thanks for your response. some time we need to have only idea regard the problem. Then we can collect more information by themselves.

Comment: @ArifKhan To gather ideas and clearify the problem you have the comments section.